# Denying access to all ports except those which are required for browsing and receiving updates

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

Recently I was trying to restrict incoming traffic to my laptop on all ports except those which are essential in work of such protocols as http, https, ssh. I was using iptables as a netfilter configuration solution. But after entering this command

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m multiport ! --dports 80,443,53,21,22 -j DROP
```

to restrict access to all ports except: 80, 443, 22, 53(for DNS to work), 21, 22, I obtained non-working Mozilla Firefox.
Please suggest, what other ports I should leave opened for Firefox and several system tools(dnf, snap, flatpak) to work properly?

Comment: You are misunderstanding how firefox uses ports ...

Comment: Could you please clarify your answer? What exactly I'm misunderstanding? As far as I know, web browser just automates transmission of http requests via globally defined ports(80, 443)

Comment: If you are using a personal laptop and do not plan to communicate with / access another PC on the same network, you can might as well deny all incoming connections. Your browser acts as a TCP client. So it will establish a connection with the website which your firewall will recognize as an outgoing connection and allow the wesite's responses through the firewall.

Comment: Are you doing this to restrict the useability of your device or to secure the device from outside traffic?

Comment: To secure device from outside traffic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ports that you have listed are the "well-known" *destination* ports for certain protocols, but that doesn't mean they are used as the *source* port as well. The source port is actually picked from a [random range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port) and often used as the destination/incoming port for the replies. So to achieve want you want with your approach, ports from that range should be left open *instead*. Also, your rule only blocks certain incoming TCP traffics anyway.

So to do it "statlessly" (that is, in this case, purely port-based):

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp ! --dport 32768:60999 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p udp ! --dport 32768:60999 -j DROP
```

As noted in the link above, the actual range can be checked with:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
```

A perhaps more reassuring approach (maybe only seemingly though, if you don't adopt it *in addition to* the above; as the source port does not really guarantee anything) is to filter incoming replies based on their source ports (which are often the destination ports of the original request):

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport ! --sports 80,443,53,22 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m multiport ! --sports 53 -j DROP
```

But since not all applications/protocols works purely/exactly this way, you will likely need some more exceptions (e.g. FTP? or even the no-longer-simple-these-days DNS) anyway.

To avoid these complications, you probably want to do it with a stateful approach:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack ! --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j DROP
```

Basically this means traffics initiated by others will be dropped.

You might still want some more exceptions (for the loopback interface and ICMP). Check out [this wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Simple_stateful_firewall) for more details and examples. ([This](https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/simple_firewall.rules?h=packages/iptables) might be good enough to use by the way.)

Answer (score 0):

**This assumes you want to only allow traffic that you have requested:**

Drop all incoming traffic: `iptables -I INPUT -j DROP`
Allow any specific port you want to connect to from another device: `iptables -I INPUT -p (proto) --dport=(port) -j ACCEPT`
Allow related and established traffic: `iptables -I INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT`